# Sharepoint 2010 search cannot crawl mediawiki site

Tags: sharepoint, search, mediawiki, http-status-code-301, web-crawler

Using Sharepoint 2010 enterprise search, we are trying to crawl our internal mediawiki based wiki site. Search fails with error : 'The URL was permanently moved. ( URL redirected to ... )'.

Since the wiki site has case sensitive URLs, when Sharepoint 2010 tries to crawl with lower case URL names, the Wiki says 'page does not exists' and redirects with 301 !!!

Any got a solution ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, all links crawled are converted to lower case by the SharePoint search indexer.  You will  need to create case sensitive crawl rules.  Have a look at the following post:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/enterprisesearch/archive/2010/07/09/crawling-case-sensitive-repositories-using-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

Comment: As an added note: by default mediawiki has a no-index meta tag set that will prevent sharepoint from crawling as well.