# Sharepoint search server 2010 301 redirects issues

Tags: sharepoint, search-server-2010

I am using sharepoint search server express 2010, And have bit of a trouble in crawlling. The pages that are permenantly redirected are not crawled and come up as a warrning that the url is permenantly moved, where as this isnt the case with the pervious version of search server where it would just crawl

Is there any config setting that I can change on the search server 2010

Thanks

Comment: This is the same issue as solved in this Question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6032046/sharepoint-2010-search-cannot-crawl-mediawiki-site